# Anonymous close request/Downvote

Tags: discussion

Its really frustrating to see closing vote for a question for no reason/ down vote on answers without people adding suggestion to make better. As an [example](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/173980/get-nodes-of-a-particular-content-type-attached-to-a-group) [image]

The question seems to be fair to me. Shouldn't we have comment as required input when someone do downvote/close request a question/answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no reason is given for an up/down vote, you can assume it's for the reason(s) given in the tooltips on the respective arrows.

Question up votes:

> This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear

Question down votes:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

Answer up votes:

> This answer is useful

Answer down votes:

> This answer is not useful

You can't case a close vote *without* providing a reason, so that's already covered too.

Regarding the specific question you mentioned...

That one is indeed low quality, and not likely to be useful to future visitors. "It doesn't seem to work" is not an explanation of the problem, it's just a random over-arching statement. It's not clear what the issue is, and the question isn't likely to be useful to future visitors because of that.

So a down/close vote is perfectly reasonable there in my opinion.

To answer your specific question:

> Shouldn't we have comment as required input when someone do downvote/close request a question/answer

No, there's no need, that information is already available. Forcing people to comment will just lead to rubbish comments being left, or less people voting because they don't want to have to constantly explain themselves.

Comment: thanks @Clive. Only thing I felt problem with down voting is It covers "This answer is not useful" but not why :( and since it is easy way out sometimes people may do it without giving a second thought.